# Python: Recursion: Passing some value down through the calls

Tags: python

Look at this snippet:

```
def recur(n):
    ds = {}
    x=do_foo(n)
    if foo(n): ds[n] = recur(x)
    else: return x
```

what i want to ask is ds at first iteration is empty and then it adds on some condition if true. if it recurs, on second iteration it enters at `ds[n] = recur(x)` so in this nth iteration ds is again defined as ds = {}.. OR ds retains its previous elements. If it doesn't, then how to retain the elements?

Comment: Please change that to valid python. I can't help if I can't even grasp the purpose of your code.

Comment: Or at least give a good example of what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very hard to tell what you want here as the code you posted isn't valid Python, but I think you are asking how to pass some sort of cache down through the calls.

The way to do this is to make the cache an optional parameter. That way you can call your function without a cache or you can pass it through to the recursive calls.

```
def recur(n, ds=None):
    if ds is None: ds = {}
    x=do_foo(n)
    if foo(n):
        ds[n] = recur(x, ds)
    else:
        return x
```

Alternatively, use a class which gives you full control over how long  the cache will persist:

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ds = {}

    def recur(self, n):
        x=do_foo(n)
        if foo(n):
            self.ds[n] = self.recur(x)
        else:
            return x
```

Comment: Yes how to pass some sort of cache down through the calls was what I am looking for.I thought about passing it as arg but had seen somewhere some other methods. you dont suppose ds = {} could be declared global, although that isnt advised ya?

Comment: Using a global would seem a very bad idea. The two techniques to use are either to pass it down as an argument, or to make the function a method on a class instance and save it as an attribute.

Comment: rather than class i would prefer to use memoize decorator. thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Add `ds` as an argument to the function.

```
def recur(n, ds=None):
    ds = ds or {}
    #...
    recur(n, ds=ds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like any programming language, inside a function you have variables that exist only when the function is running: these are [local variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable). `ds` is a local variable here, and only exists when the function runs. Whenever you run the function again `ds` won't be as the first one (imagine you're running two instances of the same program, even if you set the same parameters, there are two distinct situations).

For solving your problem, there are two approaches:

- Declare `ds` as global (outside any function) and refer it as `global ds` in the first line of the function
- Pass `ds` as a parameter to the function (this is the **very best** alternative to deal with this situation)