# Forwarded(?) parameters in recursive functions in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I have quite a bit of experience with C/C++ and have recently started coding more often in Python but I am no expert yet. I am noticing this interesting behaviour and I am not exactly sure what to attribute it to. I have a recursive function that looks like this:

```
def fun(param=[]):
    # do something
    fun()
```

I notice that, as I recursively enter `fun()`, the modified list `param` is 'forwarded' (for lack of a better word) along. I am surprised that I don't need to call `fun(param)` to carry `param` from one call to another. Why is that? As a C++ developer, that weirds me out.

Comment: This has been discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument (and many other places).

Comment: Some more places to dig in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158294/good-uses-for-mutable-function-argument-default-values and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427147/python-recursion-passing-some-value-down-through-the-calls